# Accessing string in a union inside a struct in C++14

Tags: c++11

Can anyone please explain how to use and access string in a union inside a structure with the help of unrestricted union?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
            int height;
            int width;
        } Page;

typedef struct {
            int test;
            union {
                Page page;
                int intVar;
                string  stringVar;
            } VarUnion;
        } VariableDataStruct;

int main()
{
    VariableDataStruct structeg;
    structeg.VarUnion.stringVar = "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Currently getting following errors on compilation:

unionstring2.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
unionstring2.cc:22:24: error: use of deleted function ‘VariableDataStruct::VariableDataStruct()’
     VariableDataStruct structeg;
                        ^
unionstring2.cc:11:16: note: ‘VariableDataStruct::VariableDataStruct()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 typedef struct {
                ^
unionstring2.cc:11:16: error: use of deleted function ‘VariableDataStruct::::()’
unionstring2.cc:13:19: note: ‘VariableDataStruct::::()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
             union {
                   ^
unionstring2.cc:16:11: error: union member ‘VariableDataStruct::::stringVar’ with non-trivial ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]’
   string  stringVar;
           ^
unionstring2.cc:11:16: error: use of deleted function ‘VariableDataStruct::::~()’
 typedef struct {
                ^
unionstring2.cc:13:19: note: ‘VariableDataStruct::::~()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
             union {
                   ^
unionstring2.cc:16:11: error: union member ‘VariableDataStruct::::stringVar’ with non-trivial ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::~basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]’
   string  stringVar;
           ^
unionstring2.cc:22:24: error: use of deleted function ‘VariableDataStruct::~VariableDataStruct()’
     VariableDataStruct structeg;
                        ^
unionstring2.cc:18:11: note: ‘VariableDataStruct::~VariableDataStruct()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
         } VariableDataStruct;
           ^
unionstring2.cc:18:11: error: use of deleted function ‘VariableDataStruct::::~()’

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is not about accessing `union`, it's about not being able to instantiate your `struct`:

> ```
>  error: use of deleted function ‘VariableDataStruct::VariableDataStruct()’
> ```

You need to provide a constructor for your `struct` that sensibly initializes the `union`.

Answer (score 0):

[Unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) with members with non-trivial special member functions (constructor, assignment, destructors) (such as `std::string`) must define these special functions as well. Since this union does not provide the designation which member is currently in use, those special member functions cannot be defined.

Use [`std::variant<Page, int, std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead.